# Metadata with pdfx - data in wrong fields

Tags: metadata, pdfx

I want to create a pdf with some metadata, and pdfx seemed like a good choice. Here is my MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
  \Title{Foo}
  \Author{Hennich}
  \Keywords{pdfx\sep test}
  \Subject{description}
   \setRGBcolorprofile{sRGB2014.icc}
    {sRGB2014}
    {sRGB2014}
    {http://www.color.org}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a-2b]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

The colour scheme comes from https://www.color.org/srgbprofiles.xalter. I simply compile with `pdflatex`.
However, when I check the metadata with `exiftool`, they show up, but in the wrong field. Among other stuff, I get

```
Title                           : Foo
Creator                         : Hennich
Description                     : description
Subject                         : pdfx, test
```

I expect

```
Title                           : Foo
Author                          : Hennich
Subject                         : description
Keywords                        : pdfx, test
```

How can I fix this?
I have Ubuntu 18.04 with texlive2017.

Comment: looks ok. In the xmp-Metadata the author is called creator, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublin_Core

Comment: When using exiftool, make sure you are using the command in [exiftool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3) so you can see duplicate tags and there locations.  PDF metadata is a real mess and there are tags with the same name in the older [PDF group](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/PDF.html) and the newer [XMP group](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/XMP.html#pdf).  And as @Ulrike points out, [Dublin Core](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/XMP.html#dc) tags are commonly used as well.  Keywords, for example, are usually in the DC `Subject` tag.